# No Packet captured by Wireshark when using mininet inside Python

Tags: python, networking, mininet, quagga

I'm doing this Simple OSPF mininet Experiment.

https://github.com/qyang18/Mininet-Quagga

Using mininet-vm, installed Quagga and confirm it's working.

Open QuaggaOSPF.py by

```
$ sudo python QuaggaOSPF.py
```

I got

```
mininet> pingall
*** Ping: testing ping reachability
h1 -> h2 r1 r2
h2 -> h1 r1 r2
r1 -> h1 h2 r2
r2 -> h1 h2 r1
*** Results: 0% dropped (12/12 received)
```

All things are set, but I can't capture any packet by Wireshark from it.

[image]
[image]

[No any packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGMo9.png)

[No any packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBrHR.png)

But run mininet directly at bash, Wireshark can catpure packets correctly.

```
$ sudo mn --topo minimal


*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2
*** Adding switches:
s1
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s1)
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2
*** Starting controller
c0
*** Starting 1 switches
s1 ...
*** Starting CLI:
mininet> pingall
*** Ping: testing ping reachability
h1 -> h2
h2 -> h1
*** Results: 0% dropped (2/2 received)
```

[image]

[Got Packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJYQ9.png)

How can Wireshark capture packets from mininet inside Python?